# How can i fix "Duplicate status message" issue while binding the Facebook SDK in my android Application?

Tags: android, facebook

I got the following response when i share text message in my facebook wall.

```
{
   "error":{
      "message":"(#506) Duplicate status message",
      "type":"OAuthException",
      "code":506,
      "error_data":{
         "kError":1455006
      }
   }
}
```

I used the following code snippet:

```
SharedPreferences mPreferences = ShareLsevenPage.this
                    .getSharedPreferences("facebook-credentials",
                            MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            String tokenVal = mPreferences.getString("access_token", null);
            Log.v("Token Value", tokenVal);

            AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, tokenVal);
            params.putString("message",
                    "I am playing MegaCandy mobile right now!!");
            mAsyncRunner.request("me/feed", params, "POST",
                    new TestRequestListener(), null);
```

Note:

**The message was posted at first time. when i click the share button after the login, second time (After getting back from some other activities) i got this error message.**

Comment: You're trying to post the same message twice - and Facebook doesn't like it. They have a specific error message to deal with duplicate posts (as you can see)...

Comment: @Lix: But there is no proper answer there, how can i solve this

Comment: The answer is not to post the same message twice. You say that the message posted the first time, but after clicking share again after logging in you get this error. You are yourself stating that you are posting the same content twice. **That** is the problem here.

Comment: @Lix: pls see  my updated Note.

Comment: This is how I see it - `1) Post a message. 2) Do some other actions. 3) Post same message again.` You see it doesn't matter if you logged in/liked something/poked someone, at the end you are still posting the same message twice - and Facebook is (correctly) preventing this.

Comment: @Lix: Here i post the image only once, after i move to my previous acitivity then come to this activity now i click the share button i got this exception

Comment: You can see this same behavior even on the main site. They simply won't let you post the same content twice (one after another)

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is really nothing more I can do here. This is not an "issue" or a "problem" - it is the expected behavior of Facebook's API.